# select the element before the last using nth child regardless of how many elements you have?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Ok, so I was reading http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/ (and looking around the web) about the :nth-child pseudo class and I can’t find anything related to the issue I have:

Is there a way to select, for example, the element before the last regardless of how many elements you have?

For example: I have a list of horizontal links in a nav bar, but I need to select the one before the last one regardless of how many links I have in that nav bar.

Does this make sense? Can that be done using the :nth-child pseudo class?… or in any other way for that matter?

I’ve been cracking my head with this one for several days already.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`:nth-last-child(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child):

```
li:nth-last-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```css
li:nth-last-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

About `:nth-last-child`:

> The :nth-last-child(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has
>   an+b-1 siblings after it in the document tree, for a given positive or
>   zero value for n, and has a parent element.
>
> In effect, it functions the same as :nth-child except it selects items
>   counting backwards from the end of element series, not the start.